# PEP-8 - Checking to See if Word is a Palindrome

Tags: assembly, palindrome, pep8-assembly

I have the input sorted out for the palindrome program but I haven't got the slightest idea of how to check whether the inputted word is a palindrome or not.

```
; Program to read name and output greeting 
            BR  main 
        name:   .BLOCK 32           ;space for up to 32 characters 
    msg1:   .ASCII "The word is: \x00" 
    msg2:   .ASCII "Enter a word: \x00" 
    main:   LDX 0,i             ; load index register with 0
            STRO    msg2,d      ;output word prompt 
    chin:   CHARI   name,x          ;read a character 
            LDA name,x      ;and load accumulator 
            ADDX    1,I     ;add 1 to index register 
            CPA 0x0A00,i    ;compares with line feed 
            BREQ    out     ;if line feed go to out 
            BR  chin        ;go to chin to read next char 
    out:    LDA '\x00',I        ;load acc with end of string 
            STA name,x      ;store end of string in name block
            STRO    msg1,d      ;output word message 
            STRO    name,d      ;output stored name
            STOP 
    .END
```

Can someone help me out on this please?  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Here's some simple C-ish pseudo-code to get you started:

```
Left = Start;
Right = Start + Length - 1;

while (Left <= Right)  
{
  if Word[Left] != Word[Right]
    not a palindrome, exit
  Left++;
  Right--;
}
palindrome
```

Comment: Could you throw me some mnemonics for me to mess around with?  The ones that I need?  If I have those I'm pretty sure I can do this then.

Comment: @HelloWorld - you've already got a bunch of them in your question, use them (and your own head)